# how to use Pyinstaller cross-platform for PowerPC architecture

Tags: python, cross-platform, pyinstaller, powerpc

salam,

i have python codes & i need run it on my embedded system.source codes are at my virtual X86 machine & i want **make executable file from my source files using Pyinstaller but for a PPC architecture.** is there any good idea except running python on my embedded system?

Comment: Good luck finding support for a 28 year old processor.

Comment: You cannot 'cross-build' a Python application. If you need to run it on PPC architecture, build the application on a PPC system.